# Informix 11.5 alternative to "drop if exists"

Tags: sql, informix

I'm using Informix 11.5 and I'd like to know if there is any alternative to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <table_name>`, since this is not supported in version 11.5.
Upgrade from 11.5 is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

The only alternative to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` is a plain `DROP TABLE` and ignore the error complaining about the table not existing — other errors still need to be worried about.